# How can we pass char value in gcc in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int funct(int *value,char **text){
    char a[]="hello World";
    *text=a;
    *value=2;
    return(0);
}
int main(){
    int a=1;
    char *ptr;
    funct(&a,&ptr);
    printf("%d %s",a,ptr);
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

Output:"2 hell"

Accepted output value must be: "2 hello World"

I tried to describe the issue with codes. The int numbers are passing from the function into the main loop without any problem. But i have a problem with char values. Also sent the debugger image for exploring the issue. According to debugger everything working clear till using the printf function. This is so strange any options for solving this issue. Possibly this issue could regional or for some reason

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu7df.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There's two things missing here. First, you forgot to allocate some memory for your `char* ptr;`,

For example:

```
char *ptr = (char*) malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

where 10 means you're allocating space for 10 characters. Accessing more than 10 characters then becomes undefined.

Second, you're assigning a value to `*text` that points to `a`, which is defined inside `funct`. This means that while your `*text` value might point to the correct string for now, after you leave the scope of its function, it's value might point anywhere, it's undefined. You might get lucky and the memory space allocated for your string `a` never gets updated, but let's not really do that...

The thing to do here is to copy each individual character of `a` to your final string. So, first character of `a` would go to position 0 of `*text`, so `*text[0]`, second character to `*text[1]`, and so on...

Most of the time though, we have `strcpy` do this for us:

```
#include <string.h>
strcpy(*text, a);
```

Which copies each character of `a` to an array of `char` starting at position `*text`.